# How do I avoid colliders in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I have a problem . The player can't get away from the enemy ai  . It's like the enemy ai is stuck on the player . The enemy ai has two colliders spehere and capsule . Any ideas might be going . I am stuck on this one. Another thing when the enemy ai get near the player . The player legs flop up and down.

Comment: I think that, I did not fully undestand your question but if you want a collider to just change a variable or trigger an event in yout logic you should set your collider as a trigger collider, like shown in this resource
https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers

Comment: Like I said I have two collider on the enemy ai . I have one that is trigger and one that is not . But if I make them all trigger will that make a different . I can go through the enemy ai . Is their another way to get around this?

Comment: I can make video and show what is going . You can get an idea of what is happening in the scene .

Comment: yeah sure that will help, what I'm not getting is if you want your enemy to collide with the player but at the same time you want to trigger an event, so that is why you have two colliders in your gameobject, or is there another reason?

Comment: I have trigger because I apply damage to the enemy ai when I shoot.

Comment: The other collider if so I wont go through the enemy ai . I am talking about going through the body. I set the all the collider on trigger and I am still having this problem. I will make a video here shortly.

Comment: do your enemy has a rigidbody component ? , in many cases that has solved my problem

Comment: No . But here is the video link.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/v1sqz4k5v3i2nre/My.mp4

Comment: I added a rigidbody to the enmey ai . It's still doing the same thing.

Comment: ok, seems a little tricky let me make some tests, to try to recreate the error. your games is looking so good btw

Comment: Do you mean send you the project ?

Comment: no I just trying to resemble the error with basic primitives, the only things that comes to my mind is to add the rgidbody then change the collision Detection Mode 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html

or maybe try to change the minimum penetration property that maybe can be causing the overlap  (Edit > project settings > physics > Min Penetration).

Comment: also, in which version of unity are you currentl yworking?

Comment: It's the nav mesh agent I have attach to the script.

Comment: Well that makes sense also, XD I really tried to help, I you have any other doubts, you can totally ask me, also you game looks so cool so if you want so help I could totally help you in any you need. Greetings

Comment: I am still having the problem . It the nav mesh agent. The reason why I have a nav mesh agent attach to the enemy is before . I had to enemy ai's and they would going through each , I need help getting around this problem . That's it.

Comment: How do I pause music animations and all  in the scene until the animation countdown is  done ?

Comment: try with 
     if (Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 1 && !Animator.IsInTransition(0))

the zero state the element in the queue getting the  most recent

Comment: Are you talking about pause music animations and all in the scene until the animation countdown is done question?